# How to get name of owners, their object names and sizes of this object in one query?

Tags: oracle, object, size, owner

I want to check which of user's objects are the biggest. So I made query gives me total size of objects every user:

```
select
  owner,
  tablespace_name,
  round((sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024),2) as size_in_gb,
  (select round((sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024),2) from v$datafile) as total_space_in_gb
from
   dba_segments
where
   owner like 'OPS$%'
group by
 owner, tablespace_name
order by
  size_in_gb desc
fetch first 55 rows only;
```

But it gives me only information about total size of all objects of particular user. How to check everys user objects and its size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `segment_name` to your `select` list and your `group by`

```
select
  segment_name,
  owner,
  tablespace_name,
  round((sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024),2) as size_in_gb,
  (select round((sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024),2) from v$datafile) as total_space_in_gb
from
   dba_segments
where
   owner like 'OPS$%'
group by
 segment_name, owner, tablespace_name
order by
  size_in_gb desc
fetch first 55 rows only;
```

It is not obvious, though, what your `v$datafile` query is doing.  That is summing the size of every data file, not just those associated with the tablespace(s) where the `OPS$` user has objects.  It isn't obvious that produces a meaningful number let alone a number that you'd want to duplicate on every line of your result.  But if you're getting segment-level data in your result, it isn't obvious what value you'd want in that column.

Comment: Using v$datafile query I want to show total size of database and how much every user litter database.

Comment: @pFromNorthPole - I'm not sure what "litter" means in this context.  And it isn't obvious that the number you're getting is meaningful.  If I have 100 GB of data files allocated to the database, half of that space is allocated to tablespaces other than what the users you're reporting on have access to, much of the remaining data files space is empty or allocated to objects owned by other users, it seems odd to report the 100 GB number on every line of the result.  Maybe that's really what you want, it just seems odd.

Comment: The question is - do we have on our database users who use tablespace dramatically high. So need to do report shows them their objects and its size - maybe some of these objects are old and they don't need them and they can delete it. The purpouse of this report is to show them proof that their objects have to big size.

Comment: @pFromNorthPole - I'm not sure what the total size of the database files adds to that discussion.  If someone has a 1 GB table, that's either necessary or unnecessary.  It doesn't matter if the database has 100 GB or 1 TB or 10 TB of data files.  If your database has LOB data, remember that the LOB segment will get reported separately from the table segment so you'd probably want to include the table the LOB segment is associated with in your report.  And you might want to combine the size of all the indexes on a table with the table segment to give a clearer picture.

Comment: Total size of database will show i.e. my manager the scale of this problem - if problem exists. Having this report he can easily compare size of user data and total amount of DB. Yes, I see that LOB segment displays separately. But I have still this same question - how can I lists owner, their objects and sizes of this objects?

Comment: @pFromNorthPole - The answer I posted shows the owner, the segment name, and the size of the segment.  That appears to be what you are asking.  If that is not what you want, can you clarify the question and explain what the query is showing that you don't want it to or not showing that you do want it to?

Comment: _"The question is - do we have on our database users who use tablespace dramatically high"_   That, in itself, is a fallacy.  There is not a one-to-one relation between users and TS.  A user my have segments in multiple TS, and a given TS may very well have segments belonging to multiple users.  You need to forget about tablespaces and data files and just look at segments (dba_segments).

Comment: Sorry for lack of fast response. Thank you all for realization me how it does work.